# How can use my custom tile when pin my app on start screen in windows phone 8.1 from app list

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I use usercontrol to make custom tile and now I want to change default app tile on WMAppManifest.xml to my custom tile plz help.

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="CustomTileToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateFlip>
      <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileSmall.png</SmallImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Title>CustomTile</Title>
      <BackContent></BackContent>
      <BackBackgroundImageURI></BackBackgroundImageURI>
      <BackTitle></BackTitle>
      <DeviceLockImageURI></DeviceLockImageURI>
      <HasLarge></HasLarge>
    </TemplateFlip>
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: how can change this line in code to reference my custom tile forever <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileSmall.png</SmallImageURI>